# Max values for each key RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, key, max, rdd

I have this data and want to get each key's max value. The key will be the first element (9,14,26).

```
(('14', '51600', 'Fashion Week'), 1)
(('9', '61577', 'Guiding Light'), 7)
(('9', '6856', 'Adlina Marie'), 22)
(('14', '120850', 'People Say (feat. Redman)'), 5)
(('26', '155571', "Thinking 'Bout You"), 30)
(('26', '156532', "Hello"), 8)
```

The final format will be:

```
 (9, '6856', 'Adlina Marie', 22)
(14, '120850', 'People Say (feat. Redman)', 5)
(26, '155571', "Thinking 'Bout You", 30)
```

How to select the first column as the key and the last as the value to find the maximum of the value? I tried

```py
groupbykey(lambda x:int(x[0][0])).mapValues(lambda x: max(x))
```

but it takes the second column as the value to find the max.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map` before the aggregations and after:

```py
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0][0],(x[1], x[0][1], x[0][2])))
rdd = rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(max)
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][1], x[1][2], x[1][0]))
```

Full example:

```py
sc = spark.sparkContext
data = [(('14', '51600', 'Fashion Week'), 1),
        (('9', '61577', 'Guiding Light'), 7),
        (('9', '6856', 'Adlina Marie'), 22),
        (('14', '120850', 'People Say (feat. Redman)'), 5),
        (('26', '155571', "Thinking 'Bout You"), 30),
        (('26', '156532', "Hello"), 8)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0][0],(x[1], x[0][1], x[0][2])))
print(rdd.collect())
# [('14', (1, '51600', 'Fashion Week')), ('9', (7, '61577', 'Guiding Light')), ('9', (22, '6856', 'Adlina Marie')), ('14', (5, '120850', 'People Say (feat. Redman)')), ('26', (30, '155571', "Thinking 'Bout You")), ('26', (8, '156532', 'Hello'))]

rdd = rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(max)
print(rdd.collect())
# [('14', (5, '120850', 'People Say (feat. Redman)')), ('9', (22, '6856', 'Adlina Marie')), ('26', (30, '155571', "Thinking 'Bout You"))]

rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][1], x[1][2], x[1][0]))
print(rdd.collect())
# [('14', '120850', 'People Say (feat. Redman)', 5), ('9', '6856', 'Adlina Marie', 22), ('26', '155571', "Thinking 'Bout You", 30)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If working with rdds is not a restriction, here is another approach using a spark df with a window function:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
    (('14', '51600', 'Fashion Week'), 1)
    ,(('9', '61577', 'Guiding Light'), 7)
    ,(('9', '6856', 'Adlina Marie'), 22)
    ,(('14', '120850', 'People Say (feat. Redman)'), 5)
    ,(('26', '155571', "Thinking 'Bout You"), 30)
    ,(('26', '156532', "Hello"), 8)
    ],['key','value']
)

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df\
    .select(F.col('key._1').alias('key_1'),
            F.col('key._2').alias('key_2'),
            F.col('key._3').alias('key_3'),
            F.col('value'))\
    .withColumn('max', F.max(F.col('value')).over(Window.partitionBy('key_1')))\
    .filter(F.col('value')==F.col('max'))\
    .select('key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3', 'value')\
    .show()

+-----+------+--------------------+-----+
|key_1| key_2|               key_3|value|
+-----+------+--------------------+-----+
|   14|120850|People Say (feat....|    5|
|   26|155571|  Thinking 'Bout You|   30|
|    9|  6856|        Adlina Marie|   22|
+-----+------+--------------------+-----+
```